# Manually added column not showing in windows form DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a DataGridView (CurrentLine) with a DataSet source table. I have added a combobox column with a different datasource, which works fine. The I tried adding another column, but the DataGridView refuses to show it!
I have tried adding a regular column via DataGridViewColumn and via DataGridViewTextBoxColumn (as I basically need a regular column with nothing but numbers).
I tried setting the visibility property to true.
Nothing seems to work and I have no idea why.

```
da1.Fill(Orders, Order);
da2.Fill(Orders, Lines);
da3.Fill(Orders, Products);

CurrentLine.DataSource = Orders.Tables[Lines];
CurrentLine.Columns["fkPrdctnum"].Visible = false;
CurrentLine.Columns["linenum"].Width = 60;
CurrentLine.Columns["linenum"].HeaderText = "Number";
CurrentLine.Columns["linenum"].ReadOnly = true;
CurrentLine.Columns["lineQuantity"].HeaderText = "Quantity";
CurrentLine.Columns["lineQuantity"].Width = 70;
CurrentLine.Columns["linePrdctPrice"].HeaderText = "Unit Price";
CurrentLine.Columns["linePrdctPrice"].Width = 100;

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn prod = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
prod.DataSource = Orders.Tables[Products];
prod.DisplayMember = "prdctName";
prod.ValueMember = "prdctNum";
prod.HeaderText = "Product";
CurrentLine.Columns.Add(prod);
for (int i=0; i<CurrentLine.Rows.Count; i++)
{
int product = Convert.ToInt32(Orders.Tables[Lines].Rows[i][1]); //This loop sets the values of the combobox according to the order lines in the orderline table in the dataset.
CurrentLine.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = product;
}

DataGridViewColumn LinePrice = new DataGridViewColumn();
LinePrice.HeaderText = "Line Price";
LinePrice.Width = 100;
LinePrice.ReadOnly = true;
CurrentLine.Columns.Add(LinePrice);
```

Just to be clear: the combobox works fine, and the loop to set its values also works fine. The problem seems to be somewhere with the DataGridViewColumn LinePrice.

Any idea what's going on? Why does one type of column (combobox) works fine but the other does not?

p.s. I have cut lines of code regarding another DataGridView which fills with the Order table, as that one works fine and is irrelevant to the problem so far as I can tell).

UPDATE: When I move the box to before the combobox column, it suddenly appears... Not sure why though, and it's not where I want it to be in the DataGridView.

Comment: Have you set `CurrentLine.AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`? Does the datagrid have a scrollbar and the column is just not in visible area? Is the lineprice column generated in an event or a thread?

Comment: Change `DataGridViewColumn` to `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`

Comment: @Pikoh as I've written in the post, I've tried that. It doesn't work either.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz That's a no to all of them. The current DataGridView columns take only about half the space, and there is no scroll bar.

Comment: Does it throws any errors or it just doesn't appear?

Comment: @Pikoh no errors. It's just missing.
Check out the update at the end of my post please.

Comment: maybe it is not painted. Add `CurrentLine.suspendlayout();` before adding the column and `CurrentLine.Resumelayout();` after adding the column

Comment: If You add really big width, does it show? Maybe the combobox column hides it?

Comment: Neither of those suggestions work I'm afraid (width and layout).

Also, I've managed to get to to show before the combobox and thought to use displayindex to simply change the location where the columns are shown... But now displayindex doesn't work either.

Comment: Does it work if you don't add data to your combobox?

Comment: @Pikoh YES! That's Brilliant! Not sure why it matters, but that seems to have done the trick!
Except the DisplayIndex still doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: Hmm,i'm not sure either. What if you add the combo DataSource after setting `DisplayMember`and `ValueMember`? I mean, move `prod.DataSource = Orders.Tables[Products];` after the other.Does it work?

Comment: @Pikoh I'm afraid not :\
When I do that, it doesn't solve the problem AND (for reasons unknown to me) makes the loop stop working as well, even though the loop is still after the datasource.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the loop completes without throwing an exception and that your execution gets to the lines after the for loop?

Comment: @o_weisman if there is an exception, I do not get a message about it. But I know that the loop completes correctly, because the values in the combobox display correctly (i.e. the displaymember indeed shows the proper names for the values selected in the loop for each row),
Therefor I assume it completes correctly with no errors.

Comment: Maybe just add the 2 columns (`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`) to the `DataGridView` and after that fill the data in the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`solves yout problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as :

```
  DataTable Orders = Orders.Tables[Lines];
CurrentLine.DataSource = Orders;

      for (int i = 0; i < CurrentLine.Rows.Count-1; i++)
              {
                  string product =Orders.Rows[i][1].ToString (); //This loop sets the values of the combobox according to the order lines in the orderline table in the dataset.
                  CurrentLine.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = product;
              }

              DataColumn LinePrice = new DataColumn("Line Price");
              Orders.Columns.Add(LinePrice);
```

It should be works

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't solve the problem.
I tweaked around with it a little to try and solve the issues, but no matter what I try, it doesn't work. If I place it before the combobox, it breaks the combobox loop. If I put it after the combobox, it simply doesn't appear.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the new code after change

Comment: I would but I returned my code to the original version where everything somewhat worked.

I ended up using the suggested ideas from the comments to the original post, though I still can't seem to get the displayindex property to work...

Answer (score 0):

I made use of your code and I encountered the below error during the execution of code fragment which adds "Line Price" `column`.

> Column cannot be added because its CellType property is null.

The above error can be generated if columns are added *after* you have already added rows into the DataGridView since it is not possible determine the cell type.

I managed to display the column based on the order you requested using the below code fragment. Please try to add in the new line and confirm if this helps to resolve your issue.

```
        DataGridViewColumn LinePrice = new DataGridViewColumn();
        LinePrice.HeaderText = "Line Price";
        LinePrice.Width = 100;
        LinePrice.ReadOnly = true;
        LinePrice.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();    // Define the cell type of the new column
        CurrentLine.Columns.Add(LinePrice);
```

NOTE: The `for` loop can generate error (@o_weisman also mentioned this) while making use of `i` to get hold of the `Orders.Rows[i]` row. Further, it seems that you have a master `try catch` block which is suppressing the errors. Please review your code to ensure that you have implemented error traps accordingly.